# Dynamic jquery loop with another jquery .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, post, each

I'm trying to create a loop with another jquery .each loop to dynamically create a table with information from .xml files. The result of the code below causes the last table entry to get all of the xml information which is DoM31. I don't know why this is happening.

```
function ttrpdom() {
  for (var i=0;i<31;i++) {
    var mypost = 'http://mysite/TotalDailyRes' + i + '.xml';
    var dm = '#DoM' + i;
    $.post(mypost, function(data) {
      $(data).find('opensearch\\:totalResults').each(function() {
        var res = $(this).text();
        $(dm).append('<td>' + res + '</td>');
      });
    } , 'text');
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the dynamic jQuery loop around the `.each`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop is not blocked by the `$.post` function calls. So `i` and `dm` keep on changing even though the POST requests have not completed.

A walkthrough of the code:

```
i === 0
Set `mypost` variable to `http://mysite/TotalDailyRes0.xml`
Set `dm` variable to `#DoM0`
Make POST request to `mypost`
Loop

Increment i
i === 1
Set `mypost` variable to `http://mysite/TotalDailyRes1.xml`
Set `dm` variable to `#DoM1`
Make POST request to `mypost`
Loop

....    

Increment i
i === 30
Set `mypost` variable to `http://mysite/TotalDailyRes30.xml`
Set `dm` variable to `#DoM30`
Make POST request to `mypost`

END LOOP

....

POST http://mysite/TotalDailyRes0.xml completes
Fire `function(data)` callback
dm === '#Dom30'

POST http://mysite/TotalDailyRes1.xml completes
Fire `function(data)` callback
dm === '#Dom30'

....

POST http://mysite/TotalDailyRes30.xml completes
Fire `function(data)` callback
dm === '#Dom30'
```

Additionally, there's no guarantee that the POST requests will complete in order. The request to `http://mysite/TotalDailyRes28.xml` may complete before `http://mysite/TotalDailyRes30.xml` does.

The solution is to detect the completed URL and use that to build the HTML id. Also - a GET request is more applicable in this context as the request is not altering data on the server:

```
    $.get(mypost, function(data) {
      var i = parseInt(this.url.replace('http://mysite/TotalDailyRes', ''), 10),
      dm = '#DoM' + i;
      $(data).find('opensearch\\:totalResults').each(function() {
        var res = $(this).text();
        $(dm).append('<td>' + res + '</td>');
      });
    } , 'text');
```

Comment: What I ended up doing was I used curl and grep on the server side to create a brand new xml file with the data I got from the other xml files. In javascript I only had to do the post once and then find the elements I needed in a loop. :-) Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: Plus by doing it that way I was able to reduce the amount of xml files on the server side from 50 to 2. It was a win win.